# Error when migrating work item data

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, azure-devops, opshub

When migrating work item data I get the following error:

Configuration failed due to following reason(s). 
com.opshub.exceptions.DataVaIidationException: OpsHub-012017: Field 
mapping with name : 10.1.I.31XDefauItCoIIection to 
**(vsaccount)*_***.visualstudio.com 1 10.1.I.31XDefauItCoIIection to 
**(vsaccount)*_***.visualstudio.com *II TFS Source 1411220907276 ALM TFS 
1411220907277 **_***(project name)__. Test Suite already exists

I have not yet been able to migrate any of the team projects I have due to the error.  Version control data works.

Comment: Can you confirm that your local process template is identical to the VSO server?

Comment: Are you getting this error every time you are configuring migration? Or this has been captured once only. Can you please retry the full configuration process starting from selecting end points and projects, which may resolve this issue.

Comment: It happens every time, i have not yet once been able to migrate any work item data, source control data went fine.  My templates local have not been modified, so they should match VSO.

Comment: Can you please share all the log files from C:\Program Files\OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility\logs directory. Bundle all these files in zip and send it us on ovsmu@opshub.com, we will analyze logs and come back to you with resolution.

Comment: I have this exact problem as well.  Any help would be great.

Comment: I sent the logs.  Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be a problem of the latest utility version (v1.0.0.6) when migrating projects from TFS 2013.3

I had the same problem but I've tryed to use an older version of the utility (v1.0) against TFS 2013.3 and it worked fine, I was able to migrate the data.

Comment: Older version does not support sync of test suite, run, result entity. Which has been added in 1.0.0.5. This free utility is not supported with TFS2013.3. You can try it with TFS2013 (Not update 3). It should work as expected.

Comment: This solved my issue too.  I have tried every version up until V1.0.005 and this was the first that successfully completed.