# Unable to migrate TFS2013.3 (Update 3) to Visual Studio Online using OpsHub

Tags: azure-devops, opshub

"Test Suite already exists" error appears while trying to migrate

Actually there are two similar questions, marked as duplicate with answers from OpsHub developers, but they are not solve problem

[OpsHub VSO migration - DataValidationException - Test Suite already exists](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26026019/opshub-vso-migration-datavalidationexception-test-suite-already-exists)

[Error when migrating work item data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25949494/error-when-migrating-work-item-data)

There are no any workaround and support is not here now.

So...

1. When can we expect an update?
2. Is there any workaround, how can we migrate?
3. You mentioned, that old version works with 2013.3. Where can we download older versions and see changelog?

Comment: TFS2013 update 3 will support in end of Nov, for workaround use old utility but in that test suite is not supported.for old version can you please contact to ovsmu@opshub.com

Comment: Thank you! So if I will migrate with older version I will not have my test suits at VSO?

Comment: I sent you email in order to receive older version. Thank you!

Comment: @OpshubInc. can you convert that into an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TFS2013 update 3 will support in end of Nov, for workaround use old utility but in that test suite is not supported. For old version, please contact ovsmu@opshub.com.

Comment: Additional Update. OpsHub Visual Studio Online Migration Utility v1.1.0.000 now supports TFS 2013 Update 3.